# How to remove the 2 right arrows in the taskbar windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

When I booted my computer today, I noticed these strange arrows in the taskbar: [image: taskbar screenshot]

- This is what it shows when I click on it: 
   [image: clicked screenshot]

Any idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a toolbar. Because it doesn't have enough space to show all its contents, it has an overflow menu. The double arrow button opens this overflow menu.

You have multiple options:

- Remove the toolbar (via taskbar context menu)
- Make it large enough so it doesn't overflow (you have to unlock the taskbar first, in the context menu)
- Use a different folder with fewer items

Comment: Or you can grab it by the two vertical bars and drag it left, expanding it. You can reposition it to its own row. You can also change the property vright-click it) to just show icons, no text.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'm marking it as the right answer